# Wordpress Post Date outside of WP

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using wordpress for only the blog portion on my site. I would like to display recent posts on my home page. I am able to show them fine, but the dates show up as "December 31, 1969". Wordpress sets the `post_date` column as `datetime`. Here is what I'm doing to pull it back in PHP:

```
$date      = $row['post_date'];
$post_date = date("j/n/Y", strtotime($date));
```

This isn't doing it for me. Can someone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: What does an `echo $date;` right after you get the date output?

Comment: what is displayed if you just `echo $date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you calling the posts? If you're using a WP loop then they're returned as objects, not arrays, so you would use:

```
$post_date = date('j/n/Y', strtrotime($post->post_date));
```